# Have side column appear in the middle on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a layout using twitter bootstrap's grid with three blocks A, B and C which appear in that order when they are stacked on small screens. On larger screens however, the middle block B should move to the right and A and C appear stacked to the left.

The catch is, that the blocks have unknown heights and in fact, the heights can change dynamically due to collapsibles, tabs, etc. In particular, I get into trouble when B is higher than A.

The small screen layout is supposed to look like this: (In the picture B is a very high block as indicated by using two brackets.).

```
[A]
[B]
[B]
[C]
```

On wider screens I want it to render like this:

```
[A][B]
[C][B]
```

The most straight forward code would be this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">C</div>
</div>
```

But then the layout contains an ugly gap between A and C because C is placed below the end of B.

```
[A][B]
   [B]
[C]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

will be a solution, in addition you can define order style for every div for example on smaller screen if you want B to be displayed first

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
div.B { 
    order: 1
}
dic.A { 
    order: 2
}
div.C {
    order: 3
}
}
```

and B will be first A will be second and C third

for more information about flexbox visit - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/